# Hidden field value in update panel not updating correctly

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-3.5

I'm working on employee web application project, in my application i used the 2 update panels,hidden fields and buttons. actually what I'm doing is while clicking button i need to get next employee info and save it this info. and here whenever I'll click on button which in update panel2, get employee info and I'll keep this employee id into hidden field which in update panel1 and while debugging hidden field value shows correct employee id but saving time its having old value. for this I'm facing lot problem please help me. 
Thank you

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid #CDCDCD; border-right: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #E9E9E9">
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
            AsyncPostBackTimeout="36000" />
          <div>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="60000">
            </asp:Timer>
          </div>
          <div align="left" style="width: 715px; background: #E9E9E9;">
            <div style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 45px; line-height: 140%; border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E2E0;
              padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px">
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNextChapter" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                  <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEmpId" runat="server" Value="0" />
                        ** Employee Info **
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgbtnNext" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div align="right" style="padding-right: 30px;">
            <div>
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnNext" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtnNext_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div align="center">              
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  protected void imgbtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //Get Employee Info & store it in Hidden field value=Employee Id
    //** Saving Employee Info using Hidden filed value **
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, provide some code of your application.

Comment: What happens if someone comes along and rewrites the hidden value to a new id and submits the page?

Comment: it'll update old employee information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar test on my machine, I really can't see why HiddenField is not updated. Its most likely your "Get Employee Info" is the root cause.

Also I want to correct your code a bit.

Your first UpdatePanel is doing unnecessary task, the tag UpdateMode="Conditional" is no need.

Also

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgbtnNext" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

this tag has no effect to anything because the button is not in the current UpdatePanel. By default everything in UpdatePanel is AsyncPostBackTrigger anyway, unless you have something to post back you can add asp:PostBackTrigger.